# Show payload options in msfvenom now that the -o flag no longer works

Tags: penetration-testing, metasploit

OS: Kali Linux 2.0 running as a virtual-machine (VirtualBox) inside of Ubuntu MATE running i3.

This is a fairly straightforward question: now that the -o flag no longer presents payload options in msfvenom what has replaced it? I have looked at the -h output and tried --payload-options in various places, nothing has worked. I am sure I am missing something simple but nothing has pointed me in the right direction as all tutorials and information still use the -o flag.

Here is relevant section of the help output:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/msfvenom [options] <var=val>

Options:
    -p, --payload       <payload>    Payload to use. Specify a '-' or stdin to use custom payloads
        --payload-options            List the payload's standard options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
msfvenom -p windows/shell/bind_tcp --payload-options
```

Comment: EDIT: I thought I had been using that syntax, but apparently I have been having brain-farts instead. That worked now, thank you.